# Fluid is not coming out of the inflow

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am trying to make fluid come out of its out flow like a hose but for some reason the fluid appears in random places and drops to the floor instead of coming out of the out flow

[image]

How do i make sure it actually comes out of the inflow?

I also have the blend file here
[image]

Comment: Please add more info to your question. How have you set up your scene? Where and what is your inflow mesh? What settings are you using on your domain and inflow? Where and what is your domain mesh (and what dimensions)? Have you Applied Scale to each of your meshes?

Comment: The scene should be set,The flow object is a circle that has been extruded its on the close to the side of the cube but it is still inside the domain,my domain mesh is just a cub i got from quicck effects and i have not applied the scale to my meshes actually

Comment: Please use the Edit link under your question to add screenshots showing all those details, including the settings of your domain and inflow objects.

Comment: I linked a blend file